# Articles not shown in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

After upgrading my Joomla site from 1.5 to 2.5 the articles on my site aren't displaying anymore. Only the title of the articles is shown.

Does anybody know what could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

go to the jupgrade/template/html folder and delete or rename the com_content folder

Then it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *user* linked to a contact that is *unpublished*, the articles written by this user won't show up in the front. It may be the reason articles are not shown.

Please check if you have a unpublished contact linked to user that wrote the articles. Also check the trashed contacts for this. The solution would be to publish the contact or to completely remove them, so *empty the trash*.

Check this [link](https://docs.joomla.org/Disappearing_articles_after_2.5_upgrade)